# Visual Studio Web Essentials Typescript preview window doesn't work with Typescript 0.8.1

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I'm running the Web Essentials 1.8 add-in for Visual Studio 2012. Using the original TypeScript release (0.8.0), I found the "preview window" and "compile on save" features that Web Essentials added to be invaluable. However, after installing the latest version of TypeScript (0.8.1),  Web Essentials seems to have lost track of where the compiler is, or something to that effect, as none of the TypeScript features work anymore. Is this a configuration change I need to make, or is it a bug that we just need to wait to get fixed? Or have I managed to do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tweet by Mads Kristensen (author of Web Essentials):

Get a new beta build of Web Essentials with TypeScript 0.8.1 support and other bug fixes http://bit.ly/SqNWSy

Comment: The current release in the VS gallery is 1.8.5 now, which supports 0.8.1